# How to extract AWS Config rule results into a file

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS Config Rule "Required Tags", that looks for missing required tags on all resources. I want to extract the results for all "non-compliant" resources to a file for ingesting into Databricks. If the data can be extracted, I want to automate this process.

I've not found a way to this currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through AWS CLI. First, you need to get compliance details for your rule and then you need to query the results to filter only the resource names. You can redirect output of the command to the file normally, like you would do with any other command-line command. Here's the code that can solve it (I used required-tags as your rule name):

```
aws configservice get-compliance-details-by-config-rule --config-rule-name required-tags --compliance-types "NON_COMPLIANT" --query "EvaluationResults[*].EvaluationResultIdentifier.EvaluationResultQualifier.ResourceId" > resources.txt
```